# User object returned from Graph API occasionally missing first_name or last_name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sometimes when requesting users via Graph API, the objects returned are missing either the "first_name" or the "last_name" key/value pairs.

I haven't quite been able to find the pattern. Most of the time it's the "last_name" that is missing, but sometimes it's the "first_name". The "name" field typically contains what looks like a valid "[first_name] [last_name]" pair. Sometimes when the "last_name" is missing, "first_name" contains the same value as "name". Other times the value appears to be what you'd expect the "first_name" value to be based on the value of "name".

This happens for regular users (not test, which was apparently reported as bug in the past) and for a variety of locales (including en_US).

When is the first_name and/or last_name not available when requesting users from the Graph API?

Update:
Investigating this further, I noticed that occasionally what appears to be the last name is provided in the "middle_name" field instead. The registration form does not ask for a middle name, but looking at account settings I can see that one can provide an optional middle name, although the last_name is still required.

Does anyone have any feedback about whether this is a bug or if I'm running into old data that did not meet the same restrictions that are currently in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this query: `fql?q=select name,first_name,last_name from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name`  I have friends from various parts of the world and not one of them are missing first or last.

Comment: Myself and all of our testers also always get the first and last name as expected, but I can see from the server logs that it's not so for some. I did run the fql query you suggested for known problematic UIDs and first_name or last_name was blank.

Comment: Did you run it from your app or from graph API explorer?  It's possible your app might not be handling double-byte character set data correctly.

Comment: I did indeed run it from the graph API explorer.

Comment: Well if the graph explorer tool wont give it to you, then you cannot get that information.  If you know the person has a first/last name specified in their profile that is not getting pulled from the Graph, then it is a bug that you should file at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.  Report back here with the bug # so other StackOverflow user who come across this issue can see the bug.

Comment: I'll try submitting a bug. The profile shows what matches the "name" value, so it wasn't clear whether this was definitely a bug or data that doesn't meet new formats. Thanks.

Comment: Did you submit this as a bug?  Has Facebook fixed it?  Could you post a link to the defect here please?

Comment: I did indeed file this as [a bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/344777258878150). It was last updated on 2/13, when Facebook put it into "Triaged" state. Sadly no updates since then.

Comment: Since this issue is a bug, can you please mark this answer as accepted (since we determined together that this is a bug...and sometimes the correct answer is that it is a bug)?  Thanks.